# React native project Renaming package name causing this issue - Cannot read property 'endsWith' of null at Database

Tags: android, react-native

Cannot read property 'endsWith' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'endsWith' of null at Database (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lvpeiConnect&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:98666:25) at anonymous (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lvpeiConnect&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:95868:76) at getModule (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lvpeiConnect&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:95938:22) at errorLog (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lvpeiConnect&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:95693:59) at handleError (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lvpeiConnect&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:356809:27) at anonymous (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lvpeiConnect&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:356813:16) at reportFatalError (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lvpeiConnect&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:1015:39) at __guard (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lvpeiConnect&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2512:89) at callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.lvpeiConnect&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2319:21)

In existing project I tried changing package name.
Did npm install again
.gradlew clean
and then ran  react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

And getting this issue
[image]